# XmlReader fails

Tags: c#, .net, xmlreader, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I am trying to read a configuration file on my Netduino Plus 2 using the .NET Micro Framework.
I have copied most of the code from this blog post by Marco Minerva
[Saving settings to XML Configuration Files](http://mikedodaro.net/2011/12/14/xml-configuration-files-for-net-micro-framework-applications-english/) the only difference is that I have another way of accessing my SD card.

```
private static void LoadConfiguration()
    {
        const string filePath = @"SD\\Application.config";
        using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            ConfigurationManager.Load(stream);
        }
    }
```

On the SD card is a file "Application.config" with the following content in UTF8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
    <add key="Key1" value="Value1" />
    <add key="Key2" value="Value2" />
    <add key="Key3" value="Value3" />
    <add key="hostName" value="www.google.it" />
    <add key="port" value="25" />
    <add key="randomkey" value="randomvalue"/>
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The below code is breaking on row 3 with the following error:
*"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Xml.dll"*

```
public static class ConfigurationManager
{
private const string APPSETTINGS_SECTION = "appSettings";
private const string ADD = "add";
private const string KEY = "key";
private const string VALUE = "value";

private static Hashtable appSettings;

static ConfigurationManager()
{
    appSettings = new Hashtable();
}

public static string GetAppSetting(string key)
{
    return GetAppSetting(key, null);
}

public static string GetAppSetting(string key, string defaultValue)
{
    if (!appSettings.Contains(key))
    return defaultValue;
    return (string)appSettings[key];
}

public static void Load(Stream xmlStream)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case APPSETTINGS_SECTION:
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == APPSETTINGS_SECTION)
                            break;

                        if (reader.Name == ADD)
                        {
                            var key = reader.GetAttribute(KEY);
                            var value = reader.GetAttribute(VALUE);

                            //Debug.Print(key + "=" + value);
                            appSettings.Add(key, value);
                        }
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

What have I missed?

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: breaking on row 3 of the xml file?   What does APPSETTINGS_SECTION equal.

Comment: @Sorceri Sorry, missed some of the code. The post is updated now. The breaking occurs in the following row: using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream))

Comment: @Cameron There is no inner exception, i only get a pop-up in Visual Studio with the options to break or continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not supported since XmlReader is to big to fit into the core of the Netduino. :-(

[Netduino Forum](http://forums.netduino.com/index.php?/topic/2476-xmlreadercreate-method-not-supported/)